# How to apply an algorithm for a C# container like functor in C++?

Tags: c#, c++

In C++ to apply an algorithm for a collection or container, I overload the `operator()`. For example generate random number for a container:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class rnd_gen {
public:
    rnd_gen( int lo, int up ) : lo( lo ), up( up ) {

    }

    int operator()() const {
        return lo + rand() % up;
    }

private:
    int lo;
    int up;
};

int main() {
    vector<int> vt;
    vt.push_back( 3 );
    vt.push_back( 1 );
    vt.push_back( 2 );
    generate( vt.begin(), vt.end(), rnd_gen( 10, 100 ) );
}
```

Is is possible to perform these kinds of operation without explicitly writing a for loop? Or any closest equivalent approach in C#.

Thanks,
Chan

Comment: You mean instead of generate, your `operator()` takes a parameter and returns a transformed value, replacing the original value?

Comment: @Skurmedel: Yes, that's what I want.

Comment: In the future, it would be helpful if your questions contained more descriptive descriptions of what you are trying to do rather than blocks of code in the language you are used to working in. This way people who are proficient in your target language will be more likely to help you even if they are not familiar with your source language.

Comment: @unholysampler: Thanks for your feedback. I will try to be more explicit in my question next time.

Comment: C# has a lot of generic algorithms in the System.Linq namespace. though they are trying very hard to appear otherwise

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, in C# the canonical way to do this is using LINQ:

```
Random r = new Random();
List<int> randomInts = Enumerable.Repeat(0,3) // create 3 dummy placeholder values
                                 .Select( x => r.Next(10,100) )
                                 .ToList();
```

Breaking the above code down:

```
Enumerable.Range(0,3)          => creates sequence of value '0' repeated 3 times
.Select( x => r.Next(10,100) ) => uses the Select (projection) operator 
                                  with a lambda expression to calculate 3 random
                                  values (the value of x is ignored)
.ToList()                      => materializes the resulting sequence as List<int>
```

In .NET, [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa904594.aspx) (Language Integrated Query) provides a rich set of operators to compose and operate on sequences, and to express queries in against collections in your code.

Comment: Very quick and precise ;) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Linq is your friend:

```
var myList = new List<int>() {3,1,2};
var rand = new Random();    
var randList = myList.Select(x=>rand.Next(10,100)).ToList();
```

Understand that the Select() Linq function uses a foreach loop internally to iterate through the source enumerable, but as we're not explicitly writing a loop it meets your criteria.